# Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm developing a Flutter Plugin that uses AndroidView to display native Android views

But I get the following Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: type
```

I can't figure out why it happens. Can someone explain the origin of this exception?

I thought you have to register the view-type in `PluginName.java` like this:

```
@Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
    binding.getPlatformViewRegistry()
           .registerViewFactory("type", new ViewFactory());
  }
```

And in main.dart of the example app simple use that view type:

```
AndroidView(
          viewType: "type",
          layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          creationParams: creationParams,
          creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
        )
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(